# Mysql temporary database in codeigniter?

Tags: mysql, database, codeigniter, temporary

i have a deployment to do within 2 days time and for the last three days i have been busy trying to understand this one thing am stuck in. It probably might be very silly of me but please take me as a newbie.

I am using an opensource software php opensource pos and it is made on CI. Now the issue is that the reports in the application are different than what my client wants. I want to change that to the way they want it but i cant.

this is the code:

```
$this->db->select('sale_date, sum(total) as total, sum(profit) as profit');
  $this->db->from('sales_items_temp');
  if ($inputs['sale_type'] == 'sales')
  {
   $this->db->where('quantity_purchased > 0');
  }
  elseif ($inputs['sale_type'] == 'returns')
  {
   $this->db->where('quantity_purchased < 0');
  }

  $this->db->group_by('sale_date');
  $this->db->having('sale_date BETWEEN "'. $inputs['start_date']. '" and "'. $inputs['end_date'].'"');
  $this->db->order_by('sale_date');
  return $this->db->get()->result_array();
```

every thing is working fine and as expected. Now i need to make some changes but the issue is i cannot find the temp database to see which fields it has. This database table (the temp one) is being used in all the reports functions, same database.

Can some one be so helpful and explain me the way it works, or how is that i can make a change to it!?

The scenario is that it is giving a summary of all the sales in the selected date range as total. I want a break down in terms of cash, credit, credit card, debit card etc.

I have another report which shows that, but not in date wise as in not saying how much in which day but in total of the date range. This one gives the total as in total sales in a day but not the break up of it as in what was what.

You can login here first:
https://demo.phppointofsale.com/index.php/login (id and password is saved on the page)

Then you can paste this link on the address bar and see the report.
https://demo.phppointofsale.com/index.php/reports/summary_sales/1969-12-31/2012-03-13/all/0

I need it to be a breakdown of the total and remove the tax, profit and subtotal columns and change that with the kind of payment as in cash | credit | cheque etc and then a total for that day.

PS: I am sorry for such a big writing but i am really stuck, please help me out. Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you want to read up on CI **Active Records** go here: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html

Comment: thank you for the information. I will see if it can help thank you!

Comment: i want to know where the sale_items_temp table is!

Comment: in your MYSQL... as @stormdrain stated, check the paths for `database.php` config

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The table name is `sales_items_temp`.

To see the actual database config (for database name, host, etc), look in either `/system/application/config/database.php` or `/application/config/database.php` depending on the version of Codeigniter.

To see about changing the query, check out http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html.